# What is the theoretical definition in terms of $\omega \in \Omega$ for independence in probability?

Tags: probability-theory, independence

I am wondering if the independence of two random variables $X,Y$ can be stated as follows:

The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is: $P(\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)=x, Y(\omega)=y)$. Hence, the joint probability is calculating the probability of the **set** $\omega \in \Omega$ under the "constraint" that $\omega$, when "plugged into" $X(\omega),Y(\omega)$ will **simulataneously**, cause $X(\omega)=x$ and $Y(\omega) = y$.

Then, if the set of $\omega\in\Omega$ that cause $X(\omega)$ to be equal to $x$ is disjoint from the set of $\omega'\in\Omega$ that cause $Y(\omega') = y$, then it seems I can separate them into two different sets and so I can factor the probabilities apart, i.e.:

$$
P(\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)=x, Y(\omega)=y) = P(\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)=x)P(\omega'\in\Omega: Y(\omega)=y)
$$

Is this an accurate portrayal of what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: For independence, you have that $P(X = x,Y = y) = P(X = x\mid Y = y)P(Y = y)$ by discrete Bayes.  If $X,Y$ are independent, this means that $P(X = x,Y = y) = P(X = x)P(Y = y)$, which will happen if $P(X = x\mid Y = y) = P(X = x)$.  Intuitively, this means that knowledge of $Y$'s behavior won't effect your prediction of $X$'s behavior, which is what you would want from a property called "independence".

Comment: @Mark Thanks, is there a way to think about it in terms of the mapping of $\omega$'s and partitions and what not?

Comment: I'm unsure.  Mapping particular $\omega$'s is only useful to think about in the discrete case really, and even then not a ton.  Thinking in terms of random variables $X = x$ and $Y = y$ (which are secretely functions of $\omega$, so $X(\omega)$, as you've written, but we try to keep it a secret) tends to make things much easier in my opinion.

Comment: "if the set of $\omega\in\Omega$ that cause $X(\omega)$ to be equal to $x$ is disjoint from the set of $\omega'\in\Omega$ that cause $Y(\omega') = y$, then it seems I can separate them into two different sets and so I can..." Then you might note that, using $A=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)=x\}$ and $B=\{\omega'\in\Omega\mid Y(\omega')=y\}$, one has $A\cap B=\varnothing$ hence $$P(A\cap B)=0$$ which can be rather different from the "independence" requirement that $$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's completely wrong.

First of all, not all random variables are discrete.  For a continuous random variable, $P(X = x) = 0$ for all $x$.

Second, except for trivial cases, those sets are **not** disjoint.  If they were disjoint, you'd have $P(X=x, Y=y) = 0$, not $P(X=x) P(Y=y)$.

Comment: Eh, it is not *completely* wrong; it is just not general enough.  Though the point about the sets *not* being disjoint is solid.

Answer (score 1):

You want, for any intervals $\cal A, \beta$ that are within the respective supports of *independent* random variables $X,Y$, that: "the probability that the outcome is in the *intersection* of the relevant preimages of the intervals is equal to the *product* of the probabilities that the outcome is in the preimage of each interval."

$$\begin{align}\mathbb P\{\omega\in \Omega: X(\omega)\in\mathcal A, Y(\omega)\in\beta\}~&=~\mathbb P\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in\mathcal A\}\cdot\mathbb P\{\omega\in\Omega:Y(\omega)\in\beta\} \\[1ex] \mathbb P\bigl({X}^{-1}(\mathcal A)\cap {Y}^{-1}(\beta)\bigr)~&=~\mathbb P\bigl({X}^{-1}(\mathcal A)\bigr)\cdot\mathbb P\bigl({Y}^{-1}(\beta)\bigr)
\end{align}$$

Though *more usually* abbreviated as:
$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\in\mathcal A, Y\in\beta)~&=~\mathsf P(X\in\mathcal A)\cdot\mathsf P(Y\in\beta)\end{align}$$

Or *sometimes*, $\mathsf P_{X,Y}(\mathcal A,\beta)~=~\mathsf P_X(\mathcal A)\cdot \mathsf P_Y(\beta)$

---

Compare this to the definition of independence for events.   Events $A,B$ are independent iff $\Pr (A\cap B)=\Pr (A)\cdot\Pr(B)$ .

**Note:** The preimages are *not* disjoint sets, else the measure of their intersection would be zero rather than the product of their measures.

---

The left semi-infinite intervals generate the *cumulative distribution functions* for real-valued random variables.

$$\begin{align}\mathbb P\{\omega\in \Omega: X(\omega)\leqslant x, Y(\omega)\leqslant y\}~&=~\mathbb P\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\leqslant x\}\cdot\mathbb P\{\omega\in\Omega:Y(\omega)\leqslant y\} \\[1ex] \mathbb P\bigl(X^{-1}(-\infty;x]\cap Y^{-1}(-\infty;y]\bigr)~&=~\mathbb P\bigl(X^{-1}(-\infty;x]\bigr)\cdot\mathbb P\bigl(Y^{-1}(-\infty;y]\bigr)\\[1ex] \mathsf P(X\leqslant x,Y\leqslant y)~&=~ \mathsf P(X\leqslant x)\cdot \mathsf P(Y\leqslant y)\\[1ex] F_{X,Y}(x,y)~&=~ F_X(x)\cdot F_Y(y)
\end{align}$$

---

When the random variables are discrete, this also applies to the atoms.   The probability measures of these are called the *probability mass functions*.$$\begin{align}\mathbb P\{\omega\in \Omega: X(\omega)=x, Y(\omega)=y\}~&=~\mathbb P\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)=x\}\cdot\mathbb P\{\omega\in\Omega:Y(\omega)=y\} \\[1ex] \mathbb P\bigl(X^{-1}\{x\}\cap Y^{-1}\{y\}\bigr)~&=~\mathbb P\bigl(X^{-1}\{x\}\bigr)\cdot\mathbb P\bigl(Y^{-1}\{y\}\bigr)\\[1ex] \mathsf P(X=x,Y=y)~&=~ \mathsf P(X=x)\cdot \mathsf P(Y=y)\\[1ex] \mathsf P_{X,Y}(x,y)~&=~ \mathsf P_X(x)\cdot \mathsf P_Y(y)
\end{align}$$

When the random variables are continuous, the atoms correspond to null sets (ie have zero probability measure), but we wish the property to carry onto the derivatives (called the probability density functions) when they exist.

$$\begin{align}\frac{\mathrm d^2~~}{\mathrm d y~\mathrm d x}\mathbb P\{\omega\in \Omega: X(\omega)\leqslant x, Y(\omega)\leqslant y\}~&=~\frac{\mathrm d~~}{\mathrm d x}\mathbb P\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\leqslant x\}\cdot\frac{\mathrm d~~}{\mathrm d y}\mathbb P\{\omega\in\Omega:Y(\omega)\leqslant y\} \\[2ex] F^{(1,1)}_{X,Y}(x,y) ~&=~ {F}'_X(x)\cdot {F}'_Y(y) \\[2ex] f_{X,Y}(x,y)~&=~ f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y)\end{align}$$

Comment: The relevant part of all this, to actually answer the OP's question, is the one-line "Note".